# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect when using .properties file

Tags: java, windows, inputstream, application.properties

I'm trying to read font files from windows computer this program worked as expected when it was using strings, but when I switched it over to using a .properties file I got the below error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdanai.ttf" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Below is my code that produces Error: **Note the first font doesn't give an error message**

```
PDFont verdana = PDType0Font.load(pdf, new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf")), true);
resources.put(COSName.getPDFName(verdana.getName()), verdana);
PDFont verdanaI = PDType0Font.load(pdf, new FileInputStream(new File(prop.getProperty("verdanaI"))),
                true);
```

And my .properties file:

```
verdana="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf"  
verdanaI="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdanai.ttf"   
verdanaB="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdanab.ttf"     
arial="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf"    
arialI="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ariali.ttf"     
arialB="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf"     
calibri="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\calibri.ttf"    
calibriB="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\calibrib.ttf"    
wingding="C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\wingding.ttf"
```

How do I use the properties file correctly?

Comment: My system doesn't have a "Verdanai.tff" file either.  I think you're going to have to allow for some differences in system configuration.

Comment: Hi @markspace, If your system has Verdana, then it will have the italicized version. This is on the same computer so I do know that path exists. If I replaced the `prop.getProperty()` with the string from properties file this programs works with no errors.

Comment: Remove all of the `"` characters from your .properties file.  Property values don’t need to be quoted—you are specifying a file name that starts with a double-quote character, not with `C:`.